# How can I get null if I divide null by a number in javascript/angular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a variable `budget`. I have a switch that displays `budget` in gallons or barrels. It is in gallons by default. There are 42 gallons in a barrel. So when I switch to barrels I display the value divided by 42. Here's what it looks like in angular:

```
<td class="text-right">{{barrels ? (fuelBudgets[0].budget/42 | number:1) : (fuelBudgets[0].budget | number:0)}}</td>
```

But if `budget` is `null` and it is divided by 42 I get 0 as a result but I want the result to stay as null. How can I do this so the code will handle the numbers like I want but if the value is null it will return null?

thanks

Comment: The code you posted doesn't look syntactically correct to me. What do you intend for parts like `| number:1` to do?

Comment: That's just the way the numbers are formatted. number:1 means it will have 1 decimal place for barrels and number:0 means there will be no decimals for gallons

Comment: @Pointy it is angular's filter syntax. @Snubber maybe it would be better to pull this into a controller? Then you could check for `null`.

Comment: @Sean oh right, OK.  Always confuses me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to "double check" before output, try this:

```
{{barrels ? (fuelBudgets[0].budget/42 == 0 ? NULL : fuelBudgets[0].budget/42) : (fuelBudgets[0].budget)}}
```

Or this:

```
budget = fuelBudgets[0].budget/42;
{{barrels ? (budget == 0 ? NULL : budget) : fuelBudgets[0].budget}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would add a helper method that checks if there is a null input:

`var helper = function(x, y) {
    if(null != x) {
        return x / y
    }
    return null
}`

Basic idea: check if numerator or denominator are null. If they are null return null, otherwise return numerator / denominator